# Return a new instance of the most derived class in a virtual function

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, overriding

I have a cleaner class that implements `IDataReader`, what it does is it filters any `DateTime` values that are outside of SQL Server's `DateTime` range and returns `DBNull` instead (The output of this class is being fed in to a [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) and my data source can return dates that are before 1/1/1753)

My issue is one of the functions of the interface returns a new `IDataReader`, what I would like is any derived class would not need to override the function to return a new object itself. Here is a example

```
public class SqlServerDataCleaner : IDataReader
{
    public SqlServerDataCleaner(IDataReader dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        //(Snip)
    }

    //(Snip)

    public virtual IDataReader GetData(int i)
    {
        return new SqlServerDataCleaner(dataSource.GetData(i));
    }

}

class SqlServerDataCleanerDerived : SqlServerDataCleaner
{
    public SqlServerDataCleanerDerived (IDataReader dataSource) 
        : base(dataSource)
    {
    }

    //(Snip)

    //Need to return the correct class
    public override IDataReader GetData(int i)
    {
        return new SqlServerDataCleanerDerived (dataSource.GetData(i));
    }

}
```

Is there any way to remove the need for the override for `GetData` so the parent class will automatically create the most derived form of the class in it's copy of `GetData` (assume all derived classes will always have a `Classname(IDataReader)` constructor)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflection to the rescue:

```
public virtual IDataReader GetData(int i)
{
  return (IDataReader)Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(), dataSource.GetData(i));
}
```

[GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) always returns the type of the current instance, i.e., for a `SqlServerDataCleaner` instance it returns `typeof(SqlServerDataCleaner)` and for a `SqlServerDataCleanerDerived` instance it returns `typeof(SqlServerDataCleanerDerived)`. You can pass this type to the [Activator.CreateInstance method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx).

Comment: that definitely works, and perhaps this would be better in [chat](which my employer blocks), but doesn't something about this just seem wrong/smell?

Comment: Reflection always comes with the price of losing the safety of type checking at compile-time and a small performance hit. I'm not sure if it's justified here; I would probably go with just repeating the method in each class.